# Root Asus Zenfone 3 Max

Tags: rooting, asus-zenfone-3

How can I root an **Asus Zenfone 3 Max**?
(Note that "Asus Zenfone 3 *Zoom*" and "Asus Zenfone 3 *Laser*" is **not** the device I am asking about)

I have tried using the official KingoRoot app to no avail (it says "Root Failed - Error 0x11CA2E")

Here are the device specification:

```
Build Number: MRA58K.US_Phone-13.1.4.69-20170414
Model Number: ASUS_X008DC
Android Version: 6.0
Android security patch level: April 5, 2017
Baseband version: MOLY.LR9.W1444.MD.LWTG.MP.V88.P71.2017/04/14 02:39
Kernel version:
3.8.19+
wind-kernel@droid #1
Fri Apr 14 03:01:04 EDT 2017
```

---

<s>This device is not on the list at [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)</s>

**EDIT**: It is now linked to this page